# Cos'è un "settivio"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Quell’antica ragazza* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto:

> Andammo al bosco in silenzio, io tenendola stretta per un braccio come se ad ogni momento dovesse scapparmi nel buio e dal buio ridermi.
>   
>         Dopo lei mi disse: – Potevi essere il primo se non eri tanto stupido e superbo.
>         – Io sono contento anche cosí, Argentina.
>   
>         – Te non so nemmeno come ti chiami.
>   
>         – Baldo, Baldino.
>   
>        
>   – Come?
>   
>        
>   – Baldino.
>   
>         Ma si allargò e si infittí la diceria e i ragazzi, anche i lontani fino al **settivio** del Pilone e i marmocchi come Tommasino della Serra, salivano ogni sera sul bricchetto sopra il Nano e di lassú la chiamavano a piú voci; e siccome lei non si affacciava, si diedero a urlare e sghignazzare, finché suo zio uscí col fucile e sparò un colpo a mezz’aria.

Qualcuno di voi mi saprebbe spiegare il significato del termine "settivio" che appare in questo brano? Non l'ho trovato su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato (inclusi il Treccani e il GDLI). Si tratta magari d'italiano regionale?

Ho cercato anche sui vocabolari piemontesi elencati [qui](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1398/707), ma non ho trovato questo termine (o un termine simile che inizi con "set-").

Il termine appare anche su [questo sito web](http://www.tellusfolio.it/index.php?prec=/index.php&cmd=v&lev=44&id=3289) che descrive un percorso di trekking nelle Langhe. Dunque, forse si tratta di un vocabolo di uso specifico nelle Langhe.

Comment: Mi viene da pensare che sia l'incrocio di sette strade :)

Comment: Anch'io direi, a orecchio, che sia una generalizzazione di bivio, trivio, quadrivio...

Comment: @DaG: Non sapevo che "trivio" e "quadrivio" fossero degli incroci di vie (associavo questi termini soltanto con gli insegnamenti delle università medievali). Conoscevo invece il termine "bivio", ma non avevo mai pensato che derivasse da "due vie". Allora, mi sembra del tutto logico che "settivio" sia il punto d'incontro di sette strade (ho copiato la definizione di "trivio" del Treccani, cambiando "tre" per "sette").

Comment: Ma in un bivio si incontrano tre vie, non due...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Secondo il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bivio) è il "punto d’incontro di due strade".

Comment: @Charo Ma secondo il Treccani anche un [quadrivio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/quadrivio/) è il "punto d’incrocio di due strade". :) La verità è che c'è un po' di ambiguità nell'uso di questi termini: quando una strada arriva al punto d'incrocio e poi procede, non è chiaro se vada contata come una o due strade distinte.

Comment: Hai ragione, @FedericoPoloni!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Penso che sia semplicemente un’estensione del concetto di bivio, dove la strada si divide in due.

Si può avere un trivio in cui la strada si divide in tre, un quadrivio in cui si divide in quattro fino al settivio, dove la strada si dirama in sette.

Nel libro *[Scrittura Vincente](https://books.google.it/books?id=k_EBBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT76&lpg=PT76&dq=settivio&source=bl&ots=KWnSLX6nnZ&sig=ACfU3U0tGOvc6liE4I1w8ShQVUwJdsULZw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih6svqkJ7mAhXSDuwKHaPHDuo4ChDoATAFegQICRAC#v=onepage&q=settivio&f=false)* di Alessandro Dattilo ne viene dato un esempio figurato, parlando della stesura di un testo:

> Dopo aver raccolto tutte le informazioni, e dopo averle schematizzate
>   sotto forma di scaletta, siamo di fronte a un bivio che in realtà può
>   diventare un... *settivio*!
>  Sette infatti (ma è solo una
>   convenzione perché in mareria escono continuamente suggerimenti
>   creativi) sono le diverse strutture tra cui scegliere.

In un articolo di [*Cuneo cronaca*](https://www.cuneocronaca.it/la-strada-di-san-bovo-tra-passato-e-presente) c'è un riferimento proprio ai luoghi menzionati da Fenoglio e viene data una spiegazione di settivio:

> Si racconta che tra S. Donato di Mango e Trezzo Tinella esista  il
>   famoso ***settivio*** (**sette strade che si incrociano**) dove, nel seicento,
>   le streghe tenevano i loro Sabba; ancora oggi quei luoghi hanno
>   qualcosa di particolare, di magico e anche di scaramantico.
>
> San Bovo è anche la terra letteraria, quella raccontata da Beppe
>   Fenoglio nella sua *Malora*; il Pavaglione è lì per raccontarlo. Lungo
>   quella strada intrisa di fantasia è facile immaginare come la vita
>   scorreva in quei anni di privazioni. Oggi i vecchi cascinali sono
>   diventati residenza di inglesi e tedeschi in cerca di tranquillità e
>   poesia.

Comment: Cercando "Fenoglio settivio" su Google ho trovato [quest'articolo di "Cuneo cronaca"](https://www.cuneocronaca.it/la-strada-di-san-bovo-tra-passato-e-presente) che spiega che "settivio" significa "sette strade che si incrociano". Forse potresti includerlo nella risposta.

Comment: @Charo Aggiunto, grazie

Comment: Anche su questo [articolo sulle masche piemontesi](https://axismundi.blog/2018/10/28/frammenti-di-uno-sciamanesimo-dimenticato-le-masche-piemontesi/) si legge: "Il luogo d’incontro delle adepte con il demonio per ottenerlo doveva essere una zona boschiva, preferibilmente in mezzo a **un quadrivio o un settivio** — ciò [...]". Quindi, più che trattarsi d'italiano regionale, forse questo termine si è usato di più in Piemonte perché era associato alla stregoneria.